# Unix Replace pattern using Regex when beginning and end are known

Tags: regex, unix, search, replace

I need to replace a substring in several files where only beginning and end of substring are known and the content between may var in length and type

I have trying using Regex but unable to nail the pattern

E.g. Below are some lines

1. Dragon Age Inquisition has a Lock mode for adults so that kids don't use it
2. Witcher 3 has a Lock mode so that kids cannot use it
3. Super Mario has a Lock against adults so that only kids can use it

I want to replace everything between 'Lock' and 'so' with 'check' on all 3 lines

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sed -i '' 's/Lock.*so/check/' filename
```

`Lock` and `so` match exactly, `.*` matches any substring between them. It matches the longest possible substring, so if there is more than one `so` on the line, it will replace everything until the last one.

Comment: Note that if there is more than one `so` in the line, it will use the last occurrence, which may be exactly what you want.

Comment: I am getting a slight hurdle her. Suppose the line is ' Dragon Age Inquisition has a Lock mode for adults so that kids don't use so it ' and I run the solution, it will replace all words between Lock and the second 'so'. O/P:  'Dragon Age has a Lock it'. Is there a way to make it stop at first 'so'

Comment: You need to use a tool that implements non-greedy regexps, then you would write `Lock.*?so`. Unfortunately, `sed` doesn't, even with the `-r` option to use extended regexp.

Answer (score 0):

Perl with "-p" is a great help.

Example:

```
# repperl.pl
s/(Lock).+(so)/\1 check \2/
```

Run with:

```
perl -p repperl.pl < repperl.txt
```

Output:

```
Dragon Age Inquisition has a Lock check so that kids don't use it
Witcher 3 has a Lock check so that kids cannot use it
Super Mario has a Lock check so that only kids can use it
```

It's written this way so you can modify files in place; see "Perl -i", or just use `sed`/`awk`.